# Predicate logic - What is the point of changing a variable name?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

I recently learned a bit about predicate logic, and now I am facing an exercice which is turning my mind upside down. I am not sure how I can achieve one of these, and I don't understand why someone would change a variable name all of the sudden?

Here's the original logical equation:

```
¬∀x(   ¬(∃y ¬P(x,y))   ∨    (¬∀y ¬Q(x,y))   )
```

Here are the four possible answer:

```
∃x∃y∃z(¬P(x,y)∨ Q(x,z))

∃x∃y∃z(¬P(x,y)∧ Q(x,z))

∃x∃y∃z(P(x,y)∨¬Q(x,z))

∃x∃y∃z (P(x,y)∧¬Q(x,z))
```

Here's my logic:

```
¬∀x(   ¬(∃y ¬P(x,y))   ∨    (¬∀y ¬Q(x,y))   ) // Original logic in the question

∃x¬(   ¬(∃y ¬P(x,y))   ∨    (¬∀y ¬Q(x,y))   ) // De Morgan

∃x (   (∃y ¬P(x,y))    ∧   ¬(¬∀y ¬Q(x,y))   ) // De Morgan

∃x (   (∃y ¬P(x,y))    ∧   ¬(∀y Q(x,y))     ) // Double negation

∃x (   (∃y ¬P(x,y))    ∧   (∃y ¬Q(x,y))     ) // Double negation + De Morgan

∃z ¬Q(x,z) = ∃y ¬Q(x,y)
∃x (   (∃y ¬P(x,y))    ∧   (∃z ¬Q(x,z))     ) // Variable change

∃x (   ∃y ¬P(x,y)      ∧     ∃z ¬Q(x,z)     ) // Parentesis removal by priority

∃x (   ∃y∃z: ¬P(x,y)   ∧      ¬Q(x,z)       ) // Organisation

∃x∃y∃z: (   ¬P(x,y)    ∧      ¬Q(x,z)       ) // Organisation
```

**EDIT 1:**

Thank you very much @Graham Kemp and everybody in the comments. Here's what I did, at last. Could someone validate if the logic is right? I achieved one of the answer, however, I want to make sure I understood correctly. Thank you!

```
¬∀x(   ¬(∃y ¬P(x,y))   ∨   (¬∀y ¬Q(x,y))   ) // Original

¬∀x(   ¬(∃y ¬P(x,y))   ∨   (¬∀z ¬Q(x,z))   ) // Variable Change

¬∀x(   ¬(¬∀y P(x,y))   ∨   (¬∀z ¬Q(x,z))   ) // Morgan

¬∀x(   ¬(∃y ¬P(x,y))   ∨   (¬∀z ¬Q(x,z))   ) // Morgan

¬∀x(    (∀y P(x,y))    ∨   (¬∀z ¬Q(x,z))   ) // Morgan

¬∀x(    ∀y¬∀z (P(x,y)  ∨       ¬Q(x,z) )   ) // Simplification

¬∀x(   ¬∃y¬∃z¬(P(x,y)  ∨       ¬Q(x,z) )   ) // Morgan

¬∀x(   ¬∃y¬∃z (¬P(x,y) ∧       Q(x,z)  )   ) // Morgan

¬∀x(   (¬∃y ¬P(x,y))   ∧   (¬∃z Q(x,z))    ) // Organisation

∃x¬(   (¬∃y ¬P(x,y))   ∧   (¬∃z Q(x,z))    ) // Morgan

∃x (   ¬(¬∃y ¬P(x,y))  ∨   ¬(¬∃z Q(x,z))   ) // Morgan

∃x (   ¬(¬∃y ¬P(x,y))  ∨   ¬(∀z¬Q(x,z))    ) // Morgan

∃x (   ¬(¬∃y ¬P(x,y))  ∨    (∃z Q(x,z))    ) // Morgan

∃x (   (¬∀y P(x,y))    ∨    (∃z Q(x,z))    ) // Morgan

∃x (   (∃y ¬P(x,y))    ∨    (∃z Q(x,z))    ) // Morgan

∃x (   ∃y∃z (¬P(x,y)   ∨       Q(x,z))     ) // Simplification

∃x∃y∃z (¬P(x,y)        ∨       Q(x,z)      ) // Simplification
```

Comment: fourth line, second conjunct, why removed the negation of Q ?

Comment: Because from what I understand, ¬(∀y Q(x,y))  === ¬(¬∀y ¬Q(x,y)) because of the double negation, like "For every Y such as F" === "For no Y such as no F". Isn't that right?

Comment: I think $\neg (\forall y: Q(y,x)) \iff \exists y: \neg Q(y,x)$. It should read: "Not For every Y implies F" === "There is Y such that not F"

Comment: Quantified variables are "dummy" like in integration. "Every man is mortal" is "Everything that is a man is mortal". The "everything" is the quantifier and does not mean "this" or "that".

Comment: Thank you for your answer and time, you two, I appreciate it. How would you reduce the double negation, then, according to your knowledge? "¬(¬∀y ¬Q(x,y))"

When I try to reduce it with De Morgan, it gives me this: "(¬∃y Q(x,y))". My logic source is the first example when you follow this link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws#Extension_to_predicate_and_modal_logic

Comment: I suppose, double negation cancel out, it hould remains $\forall y:\neg Q(x,y)$. That what Wiki sayys. Otherwise I don't know what is the difference between $(\neg \forall y:\neg Q(x,y))$ and $\neg(\forall y:\neg Q(x,y))$ in the 1st line above in the question

Comment: I can not arrive to an answer with three $\exists$ at its start! What I get by prenex form is $\exists x \forall y \exists z \neg (P(x,y) \vee Q(x,z))$. I hope you check the possible answers above

Comment: The 4 possible answer are what is given to me, I have no clue how the author got there, but it's from a reliable source, from my university teacher.

Comment: @Physor The difference between $(\lnot\forall y:\lnot Q(x,y))$ and $\lnot(\forall y:\lnot Q(x,y))$ is the difference between $(\lnot A)$ and $\lnot(A)$.  That is, nothing beside bracket placement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> and I don't understand why someone would change a variable name all of the sudden?

When distributing, you are overlapping the scopes of the quantifiers and *need* to be clear on which variable is bound to which quantifier.   For this purpose, we use substitution (sometimes called *alpha-substitution*) to ensure each quantifier is bound to a distinct term.   It is always best to choose a 'new', or 'fresh', variable - one which does not occur elsewhere in the statement.

Now, when $z$ *does not occur free* in $Q(x,y)$, then $\forall y~Q(x,y)$ is equivalent to $\forall z~Q(x,z)$.

Thus $\lnot\forall x~(\lnot(\exists y~\lnot P(x,y))\lor(\lnot\forall y~\lnot Q(x,y)))$ equates to $\lnot\forall x~(\lnot(\exists y~\lnot P(x,y))\lor(\lnot\forall z~\lnot Q(x,z)))$ and you may now safely distribute to prenex form (well, okay, *after* carefully using negation duality rules).

$${\lnot\forall x~(\lnot(\exists y~\lnot P(x,y))\lor(\lnot\forall y~\lnot Q(x,y)))\\\lnot\forall x~(\lnot(\exists y~\lnot P(x,y))\lor(\lnot\forall z~\lnot Q(x,z)))\\\exists x~\lnot(\lnot(\exists y~\lnot P(x,y))\lor(\lnot\forall z~\lnot Q(x,z)))\\\exists x~(\lnot\lnot(\exists y~\lnot P(x,y))\land\lnot(\lnot\forall z~\lnot Q(x,z)))\\\vdots\\\exists x~\exists y~\forall z~(\neg P(x,y)\wedge\neg Q(x,z))}$$

Also, no,  your original statement is not equivalent to any of the four suggested answers. There would seem to be a typo somewhere.

Comment: A typo, or the question asks for a sentence implied by the first, rather than a sentence equivalent to it. Good answer though.

Comment: Thank you very much @Graham Kemp, I edited my question providing more info. If you could validate the edit, I would appreciate it, and will mark this answer as accepted!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, @Graham Kemp. Just out of curiosity, I searched one of the books I use (_A Logical Approach To Discrete Math by David Gries_), but couldn't find a rule to move the Universal Quantifier to the front. Could you tell me which is the rule in question ?

Answer (score 0):

I mistyped the answer in the comment (on the question) above. Here is my derivation:

I used **Lemma 2.29** in Mendelson, Intro. to Math. Log.
\begin{array}{rc}
&\neg\forall x\quad[ \neg(\exists y\neg P(x,y)) \quad\vee\quad (\neg\forall y\neg Q(x,y))] \\
\text{In the last disjunct $y \rightarrow z$}&\neg\forall x\quad[ \neg(\exists y\neg P(x,y)) \quad\vee\quad (\neg\forall z\neg Q(x,z))] \\
(\neg A\vee B) \iff (A\Rightarrow B)&\neg\forall x\quad[(\exists y\neg P(x,y)) \quad\Rightarrow\quad (\neg\forall z\neg Q(x,z))] \\
\text{part $b$) on the "$y$"}&\neg\forall x\quad[\forall y(\neg P(x,y) \quad\Rightarrow\quad \exists z Q(x,z))] \\
\text{part $d$) on the "$z$"}&\neg\forall x\quad[\forall y\ \exists z\ (\neg P(x,y) \quad\Rightarrow\quad  Q(x,z))] \\
(A\Rightarrow B) \iff (\neg A\vee B)&\neg\forall x\quad[\forall y\ \exists z\ ( P(x,y) \quad\vee\quad  Q(x,z))] \\
\text{$f$) and $e$) on the "$x$","$y$","$z$"}&\exists x\ \exists y\ \forall z\ \neg(P(x,y) \quad\vee\quad  Q(x,z)) \\
\end{array}